# how to send a form with input type image using ajax to prevent redirecting/reloading 

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a question on the ajax request and how it would handle input type image.
i have a list of images all displayed in a certain , i need the user to click on the 
image he or she wants and when this happens, it is added to their own customized list. the list
is displayed at the bottom of the screen, which means that all the images they have chosen would appear
at the bottom of the screen in their own box. so the concept is that i have a form, with inputs in
the type of 'image'. here's the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>userList</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
//choose div containg all the images:
<div id="choose"><div id="inside">PICK AN IMAGE:<hr>
//the images will be loaded here in this form
<form type="" method="post" action="">
<input type="image" id="send" name="send" value="images/Woman-02-june.png" src="images/Woman-02-june.png"/>
<input type="image" id="send" name="send" value="images/Man-01-June.png" src="images/Man-01-June.png"/>
</form>
</div></div>
//list div that would display the images the user has chosen
<div id="list"><?php
if(file_exists("list.html") && filesize("list.html") > 0){
    $handle = fopen("list.html", "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize("list.html"));
    fclose($handle);

    echo $contents;
}
?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

so when a user clicks on an image, it's suppossed to be sent to a script which writes the data sent
into a file. the file is then loaded and displayed in the "list" . here's the script:

```
<?php
//get data from array
$pikc=$_POST['send'];
//open file to append
$fp=fopen("list.html", 'a');
//write data to file
fwrite($fp,  "<div class='msgln'>"."<img src=\"".$pikc."\">"."<br>"."</div>");
//close the file        
fclose($fp);


?>
```

as you can see, the data sent is the 'value' of the image clicked so that it is taken and concatenation is carried out
to include it in the mark up for an image. i know that i need to use ajax to do this, so here is the ajax for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min (1).js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//If user submits the form
$("#send").click(function(){    
    var clientmsg = $("#send").val();
    $.post("post.php", {send: clientmsg});              

    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

i then include another function that enables auto-scrolling and constant showing of the 'list'  i have no problem with that, it's working fine so i won't post it. the problem is, whenever i click on the first image, everything seems to be okay, data is sent to the script without any reloading,but whenever i click on the second one, i'm taken to the script page by my browser, although the file is updated with the content. how do i fix this, to stop any reloading or redirecting? please note that this is just a 'mock-test',
the real thing will have data loaded from a mysql database, and that is why i've used the same id for bothimages. 
it will look something like this:

```
//after establishing mysql connection, loading data from database, etc
echo "<form method="post" action="">
//fetch array that is holding the loaded data
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array)
{
$row['img_path']=$image;    
//echo the data within the form
echo "<input id="send" type="image" value=\"".$image."\">"."<img src=\"".$image."\">";
}

echo "</form>"
```

so that all the image paths in the database are selected and the respsective images shown using them, there are over 300 of them.
then, i'll need to send the form to the script via ajax and the same thing should happen as in my example.if the problem is with the id, i can't manually write id's for three hundred images!, i also don't think giving the form an id and then using it in the ajax process would be okay, i fear that no image would be sent, or all of them would be sent, unless i'm wrong).
so, how do i fix this? thank you in advance, i am very new to programming, so i kindly ask for help. (please note that each user, in the real version
will have their own "list" files and accounts). thanks, anything will be appreciated, even a different approach to accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Can you make the title of your post a question please? It should summarize your question then, otherwise this is really a lot to read.

Comment: @hakre - It can be a statement of intent, "Ajax for sending image without reload", or a question (personally, I think intentions can be more meaningful than some of the questions people come up with). I agree though that the title needs to be addressed. I also use a rule of thumb it should fit on one line and still make a solid point.

Comment: Yes, or add a summary on top of the post. Otherwise other uses might not be really interested in answering such a long question. That's all I wanted to hint.

Comment: Emmanuel: Think about it. What is happening? What are you experiencing? A roundtrip by the browser to the server as you "normally" (sans Ajax) would? What's the first assumption you need to make about that? Why would the browser send you on a full round trip? Is it ignoring your Ajax...?

Comment: Well Emmanuel, when you make it back, leave a comment for me using @ and my name, like `@JaredFarrish`. When you do that, SO will notify me someone's trying to get ahold of me. I think I have a good idea what's missing (hint), and it's something that's been clustering lately, with a lot of newer users with the same or similar gap in experience. It must be the season for learning Ajax methods or something.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i think that the browser sends me on a full round trip when i click on the second image because it has the same id as the first, but I've stated in my question as to why i am using similar ids. using classes to perform the request might work, i'm just not sure on how i would do that, which is why i'm here, to seek help from experienced programmers, i am very new in this field like i said. if you have a suggestion on how i might fix this (using classes?, i'm not sure), i kindly ask for your help and thank you in advance for your kindness.

Comment: You don't need to manually write IDs for your images (there are tonnes of ways to dynamically write an ID such as using part of the filename). Unless you're attaching an event to a specific element, you probably don't even need to specify IDs at all. Forms (mostly) only care about 2 attributes: `name` & `value` (and state attributes like `checked="checked"` and `selected="selected"`). I don't know what you're basing your fear on regarding assigning the form an ID and using it to bind an event (that's usually/always? how AJAX works). It's possibly—I've done it in many an application ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

On the surface, it looks like you've got a bit of *[divitis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divitis)*: the 2 `<div>`s around the `<form>` are probably not necessary (especially since they only encase one element—the form).

You noted that you're aware you re-used the id `send`, and that it will change in actual implementation; however from the php you posted, it looks like multiple `input`s with the same `id` will still be echo'd: this could cause many problems for your javascript (it might not do anything or it might produce unexpected results). What if instead of using `id` you used `class="send"`?

```
<form id="choose" method="post">
    <input type="image" class="send" name="send[]" value="Woman-02-june.png" src="images/Woman-02-june.png" />
    <input type="image" class="send" name="send[]" value="Man-01-June.png" src="images/Man-01-June.png" />
</form>
```

And then when you need to reference them in jQuery, you can use `$('#choose').find('.send')`. Additionally, if you want the data of form elements to be part of a group, you can use `name="send[]"` to create an array: `$_POST["send"]` will be a numeric array (alternatively, you can make it an associative array like so: `name="send[FOO]"`—note that `FOO` should **not** be encased in quotes).

However, grouping the inputs in this situation will be superfluous as the value of only one input will be submitted at a time. It would be applicable if you changed the form to allow a user selecting multiple images before submitting the form (use invisible checkboxes that are un/checked via jquery when a user un/clicks on an image). If you allow multiple selections before a submit, then you're AJAX will look something like this:

```
$(function(){//short-hand for $(document).ready()
    $('#choose').submit(function(event){
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post("post.php", {data:form_data}, function(){
            //stuff to do upon successful AJAX call
            var items;
            for ( var bio_img in form_data.send )
                { items += '<li>'+bio_img+'</li>'; }
            //replace contents of <div id="list">
            //with the values of the input elements
            $('#list').html('<ul>'+items+'</ul>');
        });//$.post()
        event.preventDefault(); return false;//I double up just to be sure
    });//form submit
});//document.ready
```

Otherwise:

```
$(function(){//short-hand for $(document).ready()
    $('#choose').submit(function(event){
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();//has data from only 1 input
        $.post("post.php", {data:form_data}, function(){
            //stuff to do upon successful AJAX call
            //assuming 'send' was not made an array in the input's name:
            //eg name="send" and not name="send[]"
            $('#list').find('ul').append('<li>'+form_data.send+'</li>');
        });//$.post()
        event.preventDefault(); return false;//I double up just to be sure
    });//form submit
});//document.ready
```

Lastly, it looks like you're using basic php mysql functions, which are not safe (see the warning message in the PHP documentation for [mysql-fetch-array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)). You might consider [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

**EDIT:** From your question edit, it looks like you're worried about sending an image file via AJAX. However, there is no file upload input in your code; all a user is doing is selecting an option, and you already have the file (since you reference it via `<input type="image" … src="…"`). You're only sending the user's choice, not the image file itself.

Comment: i don't completely get your answer,could you kindly explain what you're doing with the jquery? how would i apply this, and why are you adding an unordered list? all i want is to have any image clicked on and then added into the file that will be automatically loaded into the list division without any page reload/redirect. i tried giving the form an id like you have and then adding the script you posted but no data is added to the list.html file.

Comment: also, the multiple divs are for styling purposes.

Comment: Sure (not sure how knowledgeable you are, so to be safe, I'll assume beginner): `input type="image"` is a fancy submit button, so the action is submit (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) not click ("click" might work). serialize(http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) grabs all the form data (names+values of inputs, selects, etc) and turns it into json. The function at the end of `$.post` is a callback and is automatically executed upon a successful AJAX call. I put an unordered list just as a way to organise the text/names—or did you want the images in `div id="list"`?

Comment: Also, it probably didn't write to list.html because you might need to modify your PHP: in my example I changed the property name from "send" to "data" in the `$.post()` so `$_POST["data"]`, so the script probably aborted with an error/warning (because `$_POST["send"]` didn't exists).

Comment: Oh more thing: you especially want to use the submit function in jQuery teamed with the `event.preventDefault()` instead of click because that is what is going to stop the page refresh (a form submit by default will try to reload/redirect the page).

Comment: in a way it did, but i decided to go with checkboxes to allow multiple images, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You're welcome :) You might want to mark the question closed or answered so people don't respond with more solutions.